# Morley sequences and forking-independent sequences

Tags: logic, reference-request, model-theory

Let $T$ be a complete theory and $\mathfrak{U}$ a monster model, and $C$ a small parameter set. A $C$-indiscernible sequence $\mathcal{I}=(a_i)_{i\in I}$ is $C$-independent if $a_i\perp^f_C \{a_j:j<i\}$ for each $i\in I$. On the other hand, $\mathcal{I}$ is a $C$-Morley sequence if there exists a $C$-invariant global type $p(x)\in S(\mathfrak{U})$ such that $$\operatorname{tp}(a_{i_1},\dots,a_{i_n}/C)\subseteq\underbrace{p\otimes\dots\otimes p}_{n \text{ times}},$$ ie such that each $a_{i_k}$ realizes $p|_{Ca_{i_1}\dots a_{i_{k-1}}}$, for every $i_1<\dots<i_n\in I$. (In this latter case, say that $\mathcal{I}$ is "generated" by $p$.) Because a $C$-invariant type cannot fork over $C$, it is the case that any $C$-Morley sequence will also be $C$-independent. I am wondering about when the converse of this fact holds:

> **Question:** In what circumstances is a $C$-indiscernible and $C$-independent sequence also a $C$-Morley sequence?

---

Here are two examples. Let $T$ be the theory of the random graph, say with the symbol $R$ for adjacency:

First, thanks to James Hanson for the following argument that the implication does hold when $\mathcal{I}$ is a sequence of *elements*; suppose $\mathcal{I}$ is a (non-constant) $C$-indiscernible and $C$-independent sequence of elements of $\mathfrak{U}$. Let $C_0=\{c\in C:cRa_0\}$. We have two cases; if $\mathfrak{U}\models a_0 Ra_1$, then let $p(x)$ be the unique unrealized global type containing $$\{\neg(xRc):c\in C\setminus C_0\}\cup\{xRc:c\in(\mathfrak{U}\setminus C)\cup C_0\}.$$ If instead $\mathfrak{U}\models\neg(a_0 Ra_1)$, then let $p(x)$ be the unique unrealized global type containing $$\{\neg(xRc):c\in \mathfrak{U}\setminus C_0\}\cup\{xRc:c\in C_0\}.$$ In either case, $p$ is $C$-invariant, and it generates $\mathcal{I}$, whence $\mathcal{I}$ is indeed a $C$-Morley sequence.

On the other hand, if I'm not mistaken, here is an example showing that the implication does not hold for arbitrary sequences in $T$. Let $\mathcal{I}=(a_ib_i)_{i\in\omega}$ be any indiscernible sequence of $2$-tuples such that (i) $\{a_i,b_i\}$ and $\{a_j,b_j\}$ are disjoint for each $i\neq j$, and (ii) $\mathfrak{U}\models a_{i+1}Ra_i$ and $\mathfrak{U}\models\neg(a_{i+1}Rb_i)$ for each $i\in\omega$. By condition (i), and the characterization of forking in $T$, $\mathcal{I}$ is $\varnothing$-independent. But $\mathcal{I}$ is not generated by any $\varnothing$-invariant type $p(xy)$; indeed, suppose $p(xy)$ generates $\mathcal{I}$. Since $a_1b_1$ realizes $p|_{a_0b_0}$, $p$ must contain the formulas $xRa_0$ and $\neg(xRb_0)$. But there is an automorphism of $\mathfrak{U}$ swapping $a_0$ and $b_0$, so $p$ is indeed not $\varnothing$-invariant.

---

As a smaller question, does the counterexample above look right? For the main question, if there is not much to be said in general, any references that have investigated this question in a specific context would be much appreciated. I am particularly interested in whether this implication holds generally in NIP theories.

Comment: @tomasz oh nice, I think you are absolutely right!! and that theory should be $\aleph_0$-stable, right? so I guess that example completely kills the possibility of this implication holding in suitably tame theories. if you'd like to write that up as an answer, I would be more than happy to accept it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The counterexample is fine, but basically the same example works for the theory of a single equivalence relation with two classes, both infinite (which is $\aleph_0$-stable, not only NIP): if $(a_n)_n$ is an injective sequence of elements in one class and $(b_n)_n$ is an injective sequence in the other class, then the sequence $(a_nb_n)_n$ is indiscernible and independent, but not a Morley sequence over $\emptyset$ for the same reason as in your example.

On the other hand, I think in this example also you have that indiscernible independent sequences over models (or any set containing $\operatorname{acl}^{\mathrm{eq}}(\emptyset)$) is a Morley sequence. The random graph example shows that this is not true even over models. So I think there is a chance of a positive result if besides tameness, you also assume that the base is either a model or $\operatorname{acl}^{\mathrm{eq}}$-closed.

Comment: thanks, this is very helpful!! your last sentence sounds quite plausible to me; let me know if you have any further thoughts on it

Comment: I did not think too much. The only observation is that changing the equivalence relation to one with infinitely many classes (which seems like the obvious modification to avoid being Morley over a model) breaks the counterexample: either you stay in one class, which makes you not independent, or you end up with a Morley sequence.  Also now that I look at it, in the example $(a_n)_n$ itself is actually enough for the equivalence relation (not in the random graph, though, there you'd get a Morley sequence in the type connected to everything).

Comment: About that last sentence: isn't that enough in stable theories? Due to stationarity of non-forking types over $\operatorname{acl}^\text{eq}$ bases.

Comment: oh yeah, in fact there aren't *any* $\varnothing$-invariant types in that theory, right? with that in mind I definitely think your formulation in the last sentence is really the "right" one. @MarkKamsma that sounds right to me! do you think the result also holds in NIP theories? we know by tomasz' comments about the random graph example that it doesn't in simple theories

Comment: @MarkKamsma: Yes, of course. I had something like that in mind, but obviously didn't think it through.

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom: What theory do you have in mind? For the equivalence relation with two classes yes, that is true, there are no $\emptyset$-invariant types (in the home sort), basically because you can swap the two classes. For the one with infinitely many classes, there is a single invariant $1$-type: the type of an element of a new class.

Comment: @tomasz yeah, I meant in the theory with $2$ equivalence classes! (I was just processing your comment that $1$-tuples can give a counterexample in that theory)

Answer (score 3):

First a comment on terminology: A $C$-indiscernible $C$-(forking)-independent sequence is usually called a Morley sequence over $C$. This was the original definition of Morley sequence, and if you just say "Morley sequence", people will often assume you mean this notion, especially in the context of a stable or simple theory. More recently, there has been a lot of theory developed around Morley sequences generated by a global invariant type $p$ (and as you note, these sequences are always Morley sequences in the non-forking sense). But to avoid confusion, unless it's clear from context, it's probably better to say "$p$-Morley sequence" or "Morley sequence in a global invariant type" or maybe just "invariant Morley sequence".

Now to your question: In general, there is not much to say - some Morley sequences are invariant Morley sequences, and some aren't. But in the setting of an NIP theory, *every* Morley sequence is a Morley sequence for a global Lascar invariant type! Note that I had to put Lascar's name in there - I'll get to that technicality below.

Let's start by working over a model $M$, for simplicity. The key fact is that in an NIP theory, a global type $p$ does not fork over $M$ if and only if $p$ is $M$-invariant (this is Corollary 5.22 in Simon's book *A Guide to NIP Theories*). If we define $a\perp_M^i b$ to mean $\mathrm{tp}(a/Mb)$ extends to a global $M$-invariant type, it follows that $a\perp_M^f b$ if and only if $a\perp_M^i b$.

Now suppose $I = (a_i)_{i\in \omega}$ is a Morley sequence over $M$ (an $M$-indiscernible $M$-independent sequence). Stretch $I$ to have length $\omega+1$, adding an element $a_\omega$ to the end of the sequence. Then $a_\omega\perp^f_M I$ (since if $a_\omega\not\perp^f_M I$, then $a_\omega\not\perp^f_M a_0\dots a_{n-1}$ for some $n$, and by $M$-indiscernibility, $a_n\not\perp^f_M a_0\dots a_{n-1}$, contradicting $M$-independence). By NIP, $a_\omega\perp^i_M I$, so $\mathrm{tp}(a_\omega/MI)$ extends to a global invariant type $p$. By indiscernibility, $\mathrm{tp}(a_n/Ma_0\dots a_{n-1}) = \mathrm{tp}(a_\omega/Ma_0\dots a_{n-1})= p|_{Ma_0\dots a_{n-1}}$, so $I$ is an invariant Morley sequence in $p$ over $M$.

If you want to work over an arbitrary base set $C$, you run into the problem that a type over $C$ may not extend to *any* global $C$-invariant type. Fortunately, the above argument goes through if we replace types by Lascar strong types and invariance by Lascar invariance - see Section 5.1 of *A Guide to NIP Theories*. The general fact is Proposition 5.21 there: in an NIP theory, a global type $p$ does not fork over a set $C$ if and only if $p$ is $\mathrm{Lstp}_C$-invariant.

To remove Lascar from the picture, you need to be working over a set $C$ such that Lascar strong types over $C$ are the same as ordinary types over $C$. Such a set is called "bdd-closed" (well, really a bdd-closed set is one in which Kim-Pillay strong types are the same as ordinary types, but in NIP Lascar and Kim-Pillay strong types are the same). Models are bdd-closed in any theory. In stable theories, a set is bdd-closed if and only if it is $\mathrm{acl}^{\text{eq}}$-closed. The counterexample in tomasz's answer appears exactly because $\emptyset$ is not $\mathrm{acl}^{\text{eq}}$-closed in the theory of an equivalence relation with two infinite classes.

Comment: fantastic, thank you!! this is exactly the kind of comprehensive characterization that I was hoping for in NIP theories. I'll keep tomasz's as the accepted answer, since his resolves the question I directly asked in the post, but this is very helpful; it will also be nice context for me to keep in mind when I get to chapter 5 in the book